# How to remove checkout fields in opencart version 3.0.3.2

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

Please tell me how to remove checkout fields from checkout page of default theme in opencart version 3.0.3.2. For example i want to remove company postcode..

Comment: which contents from remove postcode ?

Answer (score 1):

**[100% : SOLVED]**

> File Pathe 1 :
>   catalog\view\theme\default\template\checkout\payment_address.twig
>
> File Pathe 2
>   :catalog\view\theme\default\template\checkout\shipping_address.twig

You Find this code

```
<div class="form-group required">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-payment-postcode">{{ entry_postcode }}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="postcode" value="" placeholder="{{ entry_postcode }}" id="input-payment-postcode" class="form-control" />
     </div>
</div>
```

And Remove it.

i hope it's working for you. If you are appreciate with my answer. please up-vote it. because it's very important for me.

Thanks for Advance...